# Instance of custom class as a member of another class

Tags: c++

I have a class Game, and a class Player, and an instance of Player called "player" is a member of the Game class.

```
Game::Game() : player(screen, player_image, 390, 290) { }
```

I was told by friends to do that, but I hate doing that, for two reasons:
1. When I pass the variable "screen" to Player on that line, screen hasn't been properly initialized, so I have to pass it again later.
2. It looks bad, I had never seen code like that until today when I was told to do this.

So, is there a way around it? Thank you.

On my .hpp file I have:

```
public: Player player;
```

Comment: Why is the `Screen` bound to the `Player`? If you can, always split world and render code; it will make life easier down the line when you add new objects or decide to do headless multiplayer.

Comment: `It looks bad, I had never seen code like that until today when I was told to do this.` Great rationale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to see a bit more code for your type in order to give you definitive answers.  However there is nothing wrong with passing another member field to the ctor of other member fields so long is it's already initialized.  For example

```
class Game { 
  Screen screen;
  PlayerImage player_image;
  Player player;

  Game() : 
    screen(42),
    player(screen, player_image, 390, 290) {

  } 
};
```

Note: The order in which an initialization list executes is dependent on the order in which the fields are declared in the `class`, not the order listed in the initialization list.  Hence it's important to declare the fields in dependency order in the type.

**EDIT**

OP Requested a split between header and cpp file

Header:

```
class Game { 
  Screen screen;
  PlayerImage player_image;
  Player player;

  Game(); 
};
```

CPP file

```
 Game::Game() : 
    screen(42),
    player(screen, player_image, 390, 290) {

  }
```

Comment: I don't understand your code, is that a header file? The first line of code I posted on my question is a .cpp file by the way.

Comment: @user996056, you are asking so basic questions that aren't even worth answering, as you seem to have read the first chapter of your C++ book and don't want to read following ones.

Comment: @user996056 yes, my sample is meant to be self contained in a header file for brevity.  It could just as easily be split between a header and cpp file.  I'll add an edit which displays how to do that as well.

Comment: @user996056: It's a class definition. You usually see class definitions inside header files, yes.

Comment: IMO, while the answer is totally valid, this kind of hidden and sensitive ordering is a smell of a larger dependency issue.

Comment: @JaredPar Ah, when you separated the code, I now get it, thank you! I had doubts as to whether it was normal to do this or not, but now I get it, thank you!

Comment: @user996056 this feature is named "initialization lists". Here's a link to a much more in depth discussion about them. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Comment: Ah great, that article helped a lot. My problem is only how I can get it to pass screen as a initialized variable...